# Te form + はいる question

Tags: grammar

Watching street commotion from a long distance at night, the vision is blurry:

> それは見えてはいるけれど、見えていないという状態だ。

My guess is that it translates into "you can call it a situation where (things) can both be seen and not seen". However, I don't know anything about the grammar involved with 見えてはいる. How does it work?

Comment: Likely duplicate of [Is this は or はいる: ～わかってはいるものの](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/) and possibly [Meaning of ~つもりではいる in that sentence](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15455)

Comment: This does answer my question.