# Difference between しておる and してはおる

Tags: particle-は

Source sentence:

> 日本語能力を含め社会人として、まだまだ至らぬ身であると重々承知して**は**おりますが、是非、本件について連絡を頂きたく存じます。

For saying I humbly do something, I understand it's normal to say しておる instead of している.

I read on [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/30673/difference-between-%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF-and-nominalizer-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF) that using a 'ha' basically makes it a conditional thing, which makes sense to me considering してはいけない means doing (x) is forbidden/ if you do this, it's not good or you can't go (いけない), but that doesn't make too much sense for me here.

The sentence as a whole says: Although I'm aware my Japanese might not be quite good enough to be an employee we can discuss that if you contact me.. not IF I understand my japanese isn't good enough to be an employee, we can discuss it if you contact me.

So can anyone explain why it's 承知してはおります instead of しております?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) "まだまだ至らぬ身であると重々承知してはおりますが、・・・"

2) "まだまだ至らぬ身であると重々承知しておりますが、・・・"

Both sentences are interchangeable.

If you really recongnize that you are not qualified for the job. You have two options. One is to give up for the job. The other is to keep working so that you can get the job.

If you choose second option, it's tactically better for you to admit your inadequacy and to show enthusiasm for the job.

Just one word "は" of "承知してはおりますが" can convey the nuance "even though I admit my inadequancy but・・・."

PS:

The usage of "は of してはいけない" is entierly different from "は of 承知してはおりますが."

"歩行喫煙はいけない" = "歩行喫煙してはいけない"
"盗み見はいけない" = "盗み見してはいけない"

The following sentences without "は" are unnatural.

"歩行喫煙していけない", "盗み見していけない"

"は" here just make clear the object of "いけない."

Comment: `"は" here just makes clear the object of "いけない."` <- Then, why 「盗み見**は**いい」 ⇒「盗み見していい」 or 「盗み見してもいい」, not 「盗み見して**は**いい」?

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical example of contrastive-*wa* added for emphasis. Here, contrast is established between:

- 私は至らぬ身であると承知している → I may not be the right person to be involved
- 連絡を頂きたい → I want to get involved

So this *wa* effectively turns "although I understand" to "**even** though I understand" or "although I **do** understand." Similar examples are found here:

- [what does てはいる in this sentence mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39006/5010)
- [Is this は or はいる: ～わかってはいるものの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3233/5010)
- [Te form + はいる question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23507/5010)
- [Meaning of ~つもりではいる in that sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15455/5010)

You can move this は a bit and say 重々承知**は**しておりますが, too.